# Should this question be closed as not constructive?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons, not-constructive

Recently, I posted [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16912768/asynctasks-get-method-is-there-any-scenario-where-it-is-actually-the-best-op) on Stack Overflow. Thinking a bit about it, it really fits in the definition of a "not constructive" question:

> "this question will likely solicit debate, arguments, polling, or extended discussion"

But I really think it's interesting for people who decide to use the AsycnTask's `get()` method.

Should it be closed for being "not constructive"? I hope not, but it seems it strictly fits within that definition.

EDIT:

IMHO, it's not exactly a "better" or "best" question (clearly "not constructive"), it's a bit more radical: is there any scenario where any programmer should use it or are there always better solutions? This is where I consider it could be "constructive", meaning it could be helpful for anyone trying to use it.

EDIT 2:

In case it is really considered as "not constructive", should I flag my own question or simply delete it (not sure if I can delete a question with answers)?

Comment: Though I'm not much knowledgeable in the android area, asking whether/when a synchronous approach in an asynchronous environment is good practice solicits opinion-based debate imho.

Comment: It can't currently be closed because it has an open bounty, but yes, it should be closed as not constructive.

Comment: Also you're not asking a question. You're writing that you can't imagine a scenario/use-case for this...but you never really ask a question.

Comment: Actually, I'm asking if there's really an scenario where it is the best option. Should I rewrite the question or isn't it really constructive for the community?

Comment: @EDIT This is what I am trying to make clear in my answer, it is of the same category as which IDE is better; eclipse or netbeans

Answer (score 1):

I think if you wander that your question is not constructive in programming, you should ask yourself the following questions:

*Is my question more about programming style or is it more about a concrete problem?*
*Is this answer to my question easily debatable?*

In this case your are asking the question:

*What is more efficient?*

*What is better?*

*What is faster?*

This is definitely about coding style. Like wise is the question: *Which IDE is better?*

So yes this question fits perfectly in not constructive, but don't see that as you doing something wrong or asking a wrong questions, it is just that that is not what stackoverflow is for; You should go to one of many discussion forums.